# Generalizing map-values in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, functor, multiple-return-values

Suppose I have the following function:

```
(define foo
  (lambda (n)
    (values n (* 2 n))))
```

I want to call map `foo` over the list `'(1 2 3 4)`. Hence, I create a `map-values` function:

```
(define map-values
  (lambda (f xs)
    (match xs
      ['() (values '() '())]
      [(cons x xs)
        (let-values ([(a  b)  (f x)]
                     [(as bs) (map-values f xs)])
          (values (cons a as) (cons b bs)))]
      )))
```

Now, I can do the following:

```
(map-values foo '(1 2 3 4)) => (values '(1 2 3 4) '(2 4 6 8))
```

However, what if `foo` returns three values, or four, ... etc.? I'll need to create a new `map-values` function for each case. Is there a way to generalize `map-values` so that is can work with any `foo` that returns multiple values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does what you want:

```scm
(define (map-values proc lst)
  (define (wrap e)
    (call-with-values (lambda () (proc e)) list))      
  (apply values
         (apply map list (map wrap lst))))

(define (foo n)
  (values n (* 2 n) (/ 1 n)))

(map-values foo '(1 2 3 4))
; ==> (1 2 3 4)
; ==> (2 4 6 8)
; ==> (1 1/2 1/3 1/4)
```

This is compatible with the standard schemes as well.